# Unable to run python file as .BAT file

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to run my python script as a BAT file so I can set it to run weekly.
When running the BAT file manually, the command line shows the following error message(s).
The python code runs fine with no problems in Spyder when i run it there.

The error message mentions mkl-service package and numpy, neither of which are used within the python script.

```
C:\Users\LAIADA\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:143: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LAIADA\Full TR Download - Drive.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\LAIADA\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\LAIADA\Anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried to install mkl-service but this is already satisfied.

```
Requirement already satisfied: mkl-service in c:\users\laiada\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.4.0)
```

What am I missing?

here is a copy of the BAT file too.

```
C:\Users\LAIADA\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\LAIADA\Full TR Download - Drive.py"
PAUSE
```

Comment: Does the script uses any virtual environment?

Comment: No, not in a virtual environment - does it need to be?

Comment: u need activate de 'base' anaconda env before call script, like conda activate base

Comment: There is no need for a batch file at all to run the Python script in the environment of *Anaconda 3* as scheduled task. Just configure in properties of the scheduled task as action to start the __program__ `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with __Start in__ being `C:\Users\LAIADA` with the __arguments__ `/D /C C:\Users\LAIADA\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat & C:\Users\LAIADA\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\LAIADA\Full TR Download - Drive.py"`. That should work to start the Windows Command Processor to process the `activate` batch file of *Anaconda 3* setting up the environment and run Python.